# firebase.json for cloud function configuration?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase project uses several different storage buckets used by cloud function storage triggers. Although I can change the default bucket for a particular cloud storage function in the console or using CLI after deploying it, I was wondering if there was a way to configure these settings (bucket, memory limit, zip-deployment location) in firebase.json and pick them up automatically during deploy. Sometimes deployment of the entire project resets the cloud function settings, which causes issues for our users. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure values to consume in your functions, use [environment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

From the CLI:

```
firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

Then in a function:

```
functions.config().someservice.key
```

Comment: Thanks Doug! Another user pointed me to the documentation for cloud function settings:  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy.